# Android LaunchActivity error

Tags: java, android, mobile

I am developing a basic android application for a school project. Everything was working fine until I put in a new class which acts as my file object - I write to its variables and then save the object to the SD card. However I now get a debug error. It doesn't include any references to my own code - it seems to be referring to what happens while it is launching the activity, not when it is executing my code. Any suggestions? The error message in the debug console is below:

```
Homework Planner [Android Application]  
DalvikVM[localhost:8600]    
    Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException))  
        <VM does not provide monitor information>   
        ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2194    
        ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2229 
        ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 139    
        ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 1261  
        ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
        Looper.loop() line: 154 
        ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4945    
        Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
        Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 511  
        ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 784  
        ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 551 
        NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]  
    Thread [<10> Binder Thread #2] (Running)    
    Thread [<9> Binder Thread #1] (Running) 
    Daemon Thread [<8> FinalizerWatchdogDaemon] (Running)   
    Daemon Thread [<7> FinalizerDaemon] (Running)   
    Daemon Thread [<6> ReferenceQueueDaemon] (Running)
```

And here is the code for the start of the activity:

```
public class InputActivity extends Activity {
String chosenSubject = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_input);

    // Set up the spinner and it's listener
    Spinner subjectSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.deadlinePicker);
    subjectSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {


        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {}

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            chosenSubject = (String) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);

        }

    });

    // Set up save button
   Button saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
   saveButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //saveFile();
        }           
    });        
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_input, menu);
   return true;
}
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace for the exception from logcat.

Comment: Activity registered in AndroidManifest.xml ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include the appropriate permissions in the manifest file for writing data in SD Card:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Also make sure that you include your activity to your manifest file:

```
<activity android:name=".InputActivity"/>
```